# How to tick/untick "Always check spelling before sending" option in outlook?

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook

Following link explains how to check spelling before sending a message **manually.**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-spelling-before-sending-a-message-620b24fc-9cc5-4a2f-a26b-9ff4e02cc193?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

My question is;

How to tick or untick "always check spelling before sending" outlook option with vb.net.

Comment: You want to write a script? for what? Why?

Comment: I am looking for a vb.net code like `always check spelling before sending = False`